# Are Agra main attractions closed on 31st of December?

Tags: india, sightseeing, public-holidays, opening-hours, agra

I'm planing a trip to India for the end of this year, and I want to know if Agra main attractions are closed on the 31st of December (like the Taj Mahal and Agra fort). I didn't find anything in the internet with respect to this. I only see that the Taj is closed on all Fridays.

Comment: Isn't the Red Fort in Delhi?

Comment: @Richard yes it is. But they may be referring to Agra Fort, which is red.

Comment: @thanks for the correction im refering to Agra Fort.

Comment: India does not usually observe end of the year holidays

Comment: @RedBaron so what you are saying is that all tourist attractions are open at end of year in India?

Comment: Yup. Only christmas (25 dec) is a holiday. Some places may have one on new year (1 jan) but 31 dec is mostly open.

Answer (score 2):

[The Indian government's Taj Mahal page FAQ](https://www.tajmahal.gov.in/faq_taj.html) says the Taj Mahal is open sunrise to sunset, all days except Friday. (The page also has information on the Agra Fort.) There is no mention of any holiday or new year's closures.

If this is insufficiently specific, the linked page also contains a "Contact Us" link at the top right, with telephone and email contact information.

Comment: Of course I had a look at the page before asking. And it doesn't answer my question

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade Good, many who come to Stack Exchange don't do any research first, even 'though it's expected here. Did you go on to contact the tourism authorities, either by email, snail mail, or telephone?